# Fetch c_0 and h_0 from LSTM caffe pretrained model

Tags: python, caffe, lstm

I have a pre-trained caffemodel and prototxt for a model with LSTMs.
I get the U, W and bias parameters from the model but where can I fetch the initial cell state and hidden state from the pre-trained model parameters.

Comment: What is stored in blobs cell state or hidden state

Comment: Update:
One does not need c_0 and h_0 to perform inference over pre-trained LSTM. Verified the LSTM equations manually v/s Caffe output. Just use all zeros for c_0 and h_0 and it gave correct results.

Blob: net.blobs['blob_name'] contains the output from blob_name layer. Hence in Caffe LSTM there is only net.blobs['lstm'] blob and contains the output as (Timestep, independent stream, Hidden size) dimensional output data